# Is there a benefit to stocking up on 2km eggs I won't be able to hatch until after the event ends?

Tags: pokemon-go

Is it worth picking up as many 2km eggs as possible before the Easter event ends even if I won't be able to hatch them until after the event's completion? Or should I be trying to hatch them all during the event?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you say stockpiling 2km eggs during the event, I assume you mean that in the sense that you wouldn't be able to hatch them before the event ends, rather than you are going to purposely not hatch them.

In that sense, ***yes***, you should get as many eggs as possible during this event, regardless of whether or not you'll be able to hatch them today versus a month from now, since eggs are predetermined and the egg pools are all mixed up during this event. A 2km egg with an Aerodactyl obtained during the event will still hatch an Aerodactyl even after the event is over.

Comment: Thanks for the input on predetermination of what is inside of eggs no matter the occurrence of an event!

Answer (score -1):

There is never a reason to stockpile eggs in Pokemon GO. The outcome of eggs is predetermined, so hatching them as soon as you get them is always more beneficial to keeping them around forever.

Comment: This is true; however, I am speaking from the perspective of a someone who doesn't buy incubators and can only hatch eggs at as quick a pace as possible. In reading responses I have found that the question I should have asked should have been more geared towards the predetermination of egg hatches, as now it is clear to me that I should just keep hatching 2ks as quickly as possible until the event ends. Thanks for your time and input!